# Phonegap Local notification for wp8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I am working on local notification for wp8 (PHONEGAP). Can any one done this before. Please let me know the process how to do this.

I done this with Both Android and IOS using a plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/

Thanks,
satya

Answer (score 0):

Very few details of your task.

Think, for a start it would examine the links [Local notifications for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207047(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: And if the only question about Cordova and PhoneGrap, there are examples of [Using PhoneGap in Windows Phone 8 Applications] (http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/mihail_mateev/archive/2013/01/10/using-phonegap-in-windows-8-phone-applications.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I have done local notifications both in Android and IOS. I just want to implement in wp8.  I used a plugin [https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/)